# Sending data from Servica to BroadcasReceiver to update progress bar

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, progress-bar

In `Service` I have `CountDownTimer`. I want to send progress data to `BroadcastReceiver` in `MainActivity` and set progress. How to send this data and upgrade progress bar?
 MyReceiver is not called.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int ola = intent.getIntExtra("NUMBER", 0);
            pBar.setProgress(ola);
            Log.d("dddReceiver" ,  String.valueOf(ola) );   //can't see     
        }   
    }
...
}
```

Service

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
           String message = (String) intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
           timeToWait = Integer.parseInt(message);

            CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(timeToWait * 1000, 1000) {
            int i = 0;
            Intent intentBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MyReceiver.class);

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                intentBack.putExtra("NUMBER", i);
                i++;
                sendBroadcast(intentBack);
            }
             public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                i++;
                Log.i("dddLongFinish", String.valueOf(i));
            }
        };
        cdt.start();
    }
```

Manifest

```
<receiver 
   android:name="MyReceiver"  >
</receiver>
```

After first answer:

> 11-23 14:20:23.713: W/dalvikvm(20992): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8) 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.serwis/com.example.serwis.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   11-23 14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   11-23 14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   11-23 14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   11-23 14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-23 14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   com.example.serwis.MainActivity$1.(MainActivity.java:19) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   com.example.serwis.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:18) 11-23
>   14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429) 11-23 14:20:23.723:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   11-23 14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>   11-23 14:20:23.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

In your Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver
    {
        ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int ola = intent.getIntExtra("NUMBER", 0);
            pBar.setProgress(ola);
            Log.d("dddReceiver" ,  String.valueOf(ola) );   //can't see     
        }   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("MY_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

    }
    ...
}
```

In your Service, set your intent as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent("MY_ACTION");
i.putExtra("NUMBER", i);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

If you register your receiver in your main activity, you don't need to declare it in your manifest. Also, remember to unregister it on your `onDestroy()` by calling `unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: OnCreate ... shouldn't be in Service? and how then call myReceiver from service?

Comment: `onCreate` of your main activity. In your service just call the `sendBroadcast` like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.serwis/com.example.serwis.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: There is no line. It's copied from LogCat

Comment: Yes, but your logcat refers to a line in your code where the error occurred. I need to know where the null pointer was found to be able to help you further.

Comment: LogCat doesn't refer me to any line. I passed LogCat info below my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41766/discussion-between-ricardo-and-serafins)